# How to make Asp.net Gridview header and first column frezee?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, gridview

how to make html table header and first column frezee, my code is not work all web browser.

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/avFBx/

How to make ?

css code:

```
.tbl th
        {
            background-color: Aqua;
            position: relative;
        }        
        .locked
        {
            background-color: Red;
            position: relative;
        }
        #divgrid
        {
            height: 150px;
            width: 350px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
```

html code:

```
<div id="divgrid">
        <table class="tbl">
            <tr>
                <th class="locked">
                    a
                </th>
                <th>
                    b
                </th>
                <th>
                    c
                </th>
                <th>
                    d
                </th>
                <th>
                    e
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="locked">
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td>
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td>
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td>
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
                <td>
                    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Would wou mind phrasing the question differently? I can't make any sense out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this demo out: [FixedHeaderTable.com](http://fixedheadertable.com/demo/fixedcolumndemo.html)

It is entirely jQuery and does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to put a div with another table of the same size inside the header table, and with css put the overflow scroll... but you have to be very carefull with your mesurments so they match... the headers witdth with the columns width...

Its tricky but I think it can work.

Comment: i use Asp.net Gridview Control